# Search for a string in all properties of an object in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-pipe, angular2-filtering

How to search for a string in all properties of an object in Angular 2 with TS.

I have an array of customers rendered in a table with a search box, if the user types a value I want to search for all properties values to push a customer that matches the value typed.

```ts
export var CUSTOMER: Client[] = [
  { id: 1, name: 'John', phone: '888-888-888'},
  { id: 2, name: 'Nick', phone: '555-888-888'},
  { id: 3, name: 'Mike', phone: '666-888-888'},
];
```

**The Filter Pipe**

```ts
import {Pipe, PipeTransform, Injectable} from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({
  name: 'filter',
  pure: false
})
@Injectable()
export class Ng2SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(items: any, term: any): any {
    if (term === undefined) {
      return items;
    }

    return items.filter(function(item){
      return item.name.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase());
    });
  }
}
```

In the filter pipe above I can only search by the name. I'm not sure how to approach this. Should I create a method for the Customer object that returns all property values concatenated and then search for the term on this concatenated value?

Answer (score 12):

You need to apply null check and use `.toString()` otherwise if value will be number it will not be able to use `toLowerCase()` method and will raise error.

```
return items.filter(item =>
  Object.keys(item).some(
    k =>
      item[k] != null &&
      item[k]
        .toString()
        .toLowerCase()
        .includes(term.toLowerCase())
  )
);
```

Answer (score 7):

You can loop over the keys of the item and see if any of them include the string, and return true if any number of them match:

```
return items.filter(item =>
  Object.keys(item).some(k => item[k].includes(term.toLowerCase());
)
```

Comment: I like this approach, I usually cheat and so JSON.serialize(object) and do the comparison on the generated string, but I like your answer better, thanks for the share!

Comment: Thanks @cobolstinks!

Comment: @AliAdravi this would occur if item[k] is not a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
`arrayObj = [
  {name: 'Maxim', age: 15},
  {name: 'Pasha', age: 35},
  {name: 'Lena', age: 25},
];

let filteredObj = arrayObj.filter((item: any) => {
  if (JSON.stringify(item).includes('Maxim')) {
    return item;
  }
});`
```

It would not be bad to bring it to a single register.

Comment: All posts on stackoverflow.com [must be in English](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/). Please [edit] your post to be in English. Alternatively, visit [Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/). [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/29216312)